# Shared, writable folders in jupyterhub

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

We are currently building a jupyterhub environment in a docker container and struggling with shared folders. Our goal is to set up a shared folder which is writable for all users.

In each user's home folder there is a symbolic link `~/shared` to `/opt/shared`. The target folder has the permissions `777` and is owned by the group *jupyter*. Each user is member of the group *jupyter*. However, if one user creates a file in the shared folder logged in with his account into the web app, the permissions are set to `644`. Therefore, no other user can edit the file.

I've tried to set the `umask` to `000` in the `/etc/profiles` and the `~/.bashrc` files for each user. However, jupyter seems to ignore it. Is there a possibility to configure jupyter to create new files with `g+w` rights as default? I would like to avoid setting up access control lists with `setfacl` at the file system level because it requires custom flags in the `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Great question! Did you manage to solve it? What happens if two different users would try to edit the same file at the same time?

Comment: Do you have a programatic way to add all newly created jupyterhub users to the same UNIX group? I'm failing to find this prerequisite that you brought

Answer (score 12):

1. Set a group (i.e., jupyter in your case) to shared folder `chgrp jupyter /opt/shared`
2. Allow the group to write to that directory + make group sticky (new files are created with this group instead of user's primary group) `chmod g+ws /opt/shared`
3. For each user create `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`

With following content:

```
  import os
  os.umask(0o002)
```

Newly created files will be writable by the group.

Comment: If you don't want to create a config file for each user, you create/use `/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`, which applies to all Jupyterhub users.

Comment: This works, but it should be `os.umask(0x002)` - that is, an 'x' rather than an 'o'.

Comment: @Enfors: No, umasks are usually given in octal, not in hexadecimal. It doesn't matter for the value in question (0o002 and 0x002 are both just 2), but it will matter when you try to set 0x022 instead of 0o022.